# Want to Improve the rewind function on HTML5 Video player

Tags: html, knockout.js, video-streaming, html5-video

This is not some programming question. I am working on a project where I have video files in different formats such as mov, mp4 etc.

My app is built using knockoutjs with html5 and css3.

Our Client requirement is when they play the video and use functionalities like fast forwaard, rewind etc.. there should be no performance issues with the video rendering.

Right now, I am able to render videos properly and fast forward feature works flawlessly with html5, the Issue I am facing is in Rewind, when users hit rewind, videos begin to stutter and lose frames, and to the users here rewind function is very important.

Now I want to make a consistent performance for videos of all formats.

What will be the ideal way of going ahead in order to optimize the video performance on websites.

Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you encode your video, but look into optimizing your video keyframes to see if that improves your rewind performance.

Here is a brief overview of how that might help:
http://www.lighterra.com/papers/videoencodingh264/#maximumkeyframeinterval

> ...we still want enough keyframes that seeking and fast-forwarding
>   behavior is good, because players can only jump directly to keyframes
>   "under the hood" during playback, and will usually only display the
>   keyframes during fast-forwarding and rewinding at higher speeds (at
>   low speeds such as 2x or 3x they can often play every frame). Jumping
>   to an arbitrary point in the timeline therefore becomes more sluggish
>   the fewer keyframes there are, because more intervening delta-frames
>   need to be decoded just to reconstruct the final target frame, even
>   though those intervening frames between the previous keyframe and the
>   target frame won't actually be displayed.

Comment: Yes, that helped!!  Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: Oh, good! In case anyone else has this issue, what specifically did you change to fix the problem?